# Want to implement sticky local notification in React Native for Android

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, sticky, foreground

Is there any way to keep a notification for an app stick to the lockscreen and notifications pull down in Android regardless the state of the application (running or killed) for example the Weather Channel App. But in react native.

I also want to have a custom notification with action buttons if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [React native push notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)

If you want to make it sticky and needs custom actions, you can set like below

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
    ongoing:true,
    actions: '["Yes", "No"]'
})
```

Check [Custom action handling](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#2-specify-handlers-for-the-notification-actions) to handle your custom actions

Comment: This works only for Android. Is there any way to achieve the same for iOS?